# ImportError: cannot import name 'RegisterWindow' from partially initialized module 'src.windows'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this error in my project with circular imports, but I'm not able to find it.

The errors after execution are:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "....\main.py", line 5, in
>
> from src.windows import MainWindow
>
> File "...\src\windows\ __init __.py", line 1, in
>
> from .main_window import MainWindow
>
> File "....\src\windows\main_window.py", line 5, in
>
> from . import LoginWindow
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'LoginWindow' from partially initialized module 'src.windows' (most likely due to a circular import)

Could anyone explain to me, what is wrong? I tried to route my imports and to my eye they look fine.

My imports are like this:

main.py

```py
from src.windows import MainWindow
```

src\windows\ __init __.py

```py
from .main_window import MainWindow
from .login_window import LoginWindow
from .register_window import RegisterWindow
```

src\windows\main_window.py

```py
from . import LoginWindow
from . import RegisterWindow
```

src\windows\login_window.py

```py
from src.handlers import FernetKeyHandler
```

src\windows\register_window.py

```py
from src.handlers import RegisterUser
```

src\handlers\ __init __.py

```py
from .fernet_handler import FernetKeyHandler
from .register_user import RegisterUser
```

To get the whole picture of my files, they look like this:

[image: Imports image]

Comment: in ```src/windows/main_window.py```,  is it necessary to do a ```from . import LoginWindow```?   You need to rethink your imports.

Comment: @ewong Yes, because I'm using a class from that file.